# Android espresso accessing EditText in adapter in first row

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using Espresso for testing my app. I have a listview with some data in it. I want to check the value of an edittext in the first line.

I tried:

> onData(withId(R.id.editTextKommissioniert)).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.jflArticleList_ListView)).atPosition(0).check(matches(withText("60.0")));

But I always get this exception:

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id:
>   at.stockserv:id/editTextKommissioniert' matches multiple views in the
>   hierarchy.

What can I do, to access the first line in my adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below approach , Working for me

> onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.jflArticleList_ListView))
>   .atPosition(0).onChildView(withId(R.id.edt_id)).check(matches(withText("60.0")));

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but iit was not fully right for me. This works: onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.jflArticleList_ListView)) .atPosition(0).onChildView(withId(R.id.editTextKommissioniert)).check(matches(withText("60.0")));